# Nightwatch JS - How to run multiple individual test cases?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, javascript, nightwatchjs

Are there any other way to run test cases individually other than using `--testcase` flag ?
also
are there any to run 2 single test case from 2 different test suites?

For example:

Test Suite 1

- Test Case A
- Test Case B

Test Suite 2

- Test Case C
- Test Case D

and say i want to run only test case A and C (not B and/or D), are there any way for me to achieve this on Nightwatch ?

Answer (score 1):

- Query-1:
  Using of tag is also a very useful practice while working with nightwatch. You can use `@tags` to run the testcases without using `--testcase`
  for example `$nightwatch --tag <tagname>`
- Query-2:
  No, There is no standard way to run 2 single test case from 2 different test suites as this is not a standard practice. If you think that those cases are relative and should be run at single then you should place them in one file. Or you can create a calling `index.js` file in which you can call the test case as a function and pass browser as parameters to function (The test cases which you want to run). In that case you have to run `index.js` like `$nightwatch index.js`